# Handling which Push Notifications will show when app is NOT Running

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

## Introduction

I have a basic understanding of how fcm/gcm works and how **swift applications** handle receiving and send these **push notifications**

## Problem

When the App is in foreground I have made a code where I can choose which notification to show as a banner.

I place that code inside this function inside `AppDelegate`

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
```

Which then I will filter the Push Notification by System Defaults I put in inside `NSUserDefaults` **swift 2.3** or `UserDefaults` for **swift 3**

Which I have a class for easy get and set which looks like this

```
class Persistence {
    static let defaults = NSUserDefaults . ....
    static var doShowMessageNotification:Bool {
        get {
            return defaults.get ...
        }
        set(value) {
            defaults.set ...
        }
    }
}

// you get the idea
```

Then again inside the `didRecieveRemoteNotification`

```
switch Persistence.doShowMessageNotification {
case true:
    doThis()
case false:
    break //do nothing in short
}
```

Which then I will check if the application state is

```
func doThis() {
    switch UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState {
    case .Active:
        // do some stuff here
    case .Inactive, .Background:
        // do some stuff here       
    }
}
```

This works perfectly when the app is running or on standby but won't work when app is terminated/shut down.

Is there anyway for this to work without changing the API/Server Code?

Comment: It not possible if the app has been force quit.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/26587688/4539192

Comment: I meant, I want to choose which push notifications to show, and not which push notifications to handle actions with. pardon my english 

So by my understanding, there really is no way to do this and I really should just play with the API/Server Code?

Comment: That's correct. If your app isn't running then the notification is processed by iOS and your app doesn't get called

Answer (score 1):

Technically not possible. You app can not execute this code when its not running. You can not hide notification when your app is not active.  only available way is to handle this from server code.

If you really cant do this  from server code, Work around is using `Notification content Extension.` from [Notification content extension](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-10-creating-custom-notification-interfaces--cms-27251), you can handle content to display in notification. You may change content to some default messages if you don't want to display particular notification from here.
In extension's plist, set `UNNotificationExtensionDefaultContentHidden` to false.  This will hide the default notification text received from server and display your view where you can display whatever content you want.

You can get notification detail in `didReceive` method of your NotificationViewController.swift file.

```
@IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel?
@IBOutlet var subtitleLabel: UILabel?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any required interface initialization here.
}

func didReceive(_ notification: UNNotification) {
  if(requiredtoDisplay)
  {
    titleLabel?.text = notification.request.content.title
    subtitleLabel?.text = notification.request.content.subtitle
 }
else
 {
     titleLabel?.text = "default text"
    subtitleLabel?.text = "default tex"  //or call api  to update device token with "" , if you don't want to receive further notification after this 
 }
}
```

Comment: Good answer mate. but I wouldn't be able to edit my info.plist cause that's read-only if I were to create a "settings" part of my app. I guess Server coding really is the way.