# Is there a way to suppress incoming notifications in Xamarin (iOS)

Tags: xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.ios

At work I have to modify an existing Application to differentiate incoming push notifications by the language of the news.

In Android I found a way to not send the push notification. So I could easily check for the language and only send the right one.

In iOS it seems a little different. (I'm not the Author of the existing code, so maybe I have overlooked something.)

But I can't find any function where I could intercept the incoming message.

I tried functions like `UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RemoveAllPendingNotificationRequests();`
and 
`UIApplication.SharedApplication.CancelAllLocalNotifications();`

But without any success... maybe I put them into the wrong place.

Thanks for hints and help

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, the answer is it depends.

If you cannot change the push notification on the server, then no. The system will display it as soon as it arrives as it is formatted as the notification that needs to be displayed.

However, you can change the format of notification payload so that it doesn't display but it is rather processed by the application. Then you can process it in the app similar to what you do on Android.

Comment: I don't want to change the notification. I just don't want to show it. Because the existing app works like: 2 notifications are sent (one in english, the other in german) and I need the application to just show the system's one

Comment: "I don't want to change the notification. I just don't want to show it." - it is like saying "I want go to the vacation but I don't want to travel". Decide what you want.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to change the notification. I just don't want to show
>   it...

I **don't** think it is possible to choose which notification to show when your app is not running.

If your app isn't running then the notification is **processed by iOS and your app doesn't get called**.

You can have a look at answer in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26586954/receive-push-when-app-is-closed/26587688#26587688).

Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/